# Navbar background parts in different colour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to learn react. I want to make a semi-transparent bootstrap navbar first and colour it, but because of the way the main background colour is set some parts of the navbar have different colour from the rest. How can I fix this?

App:

```
function App() {
  return (

      <div> <Navbar/> </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

App.css:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

body{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Navbar:

```
function Navbar() {
        return (

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Test</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                  <a className="nav-link" href="/">About<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link" href="/">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="/">Action</a>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="/">Another action</a>
                    <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="/">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
    export default Navbar;
```

Navbar.css:

```
.navbar{
    all: unset;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#navbarSupportedContent{
    all: unset;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.005);
}
```

[image: Image of issue]

Comment: You didn't upload the image correctly

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the css you are setting the background color to every element on the page.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Just move this rule to body and navbar separately :)

Comment: Setting body background doesn't change anything